# Editing fields in the PFUser object is not working

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

I would like to know why I am not able to update or add any fields to my current user's object.

Using this code:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!.username = "hi"
```

does not affect my object whatsoever in Parse, neither does any `setObject` call. However, when I `NSLog` the username, it will print what I just set it to from that line above...

Comment: what are you trying to update, and also you should leave that _User class for sign up or log in

Comment: I want to allow users to edit their profile and change their username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a textfield that gets the new username.

**No need to query back from the username, Just override it with the newusername**

```
var newusername = textfield.text
var user = PFUser()
user.username = newusername
user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
      //yay it was saved
    }
}
```

Comment: if you could take a look at my other question, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks